# Unity3D - Android build has no Internet Access

Tags: unity, android

I'm having trouble connecting to the internet in an Android build.
I created a simple program that checks if there is an connection. Also I set in 'Edit > Project Settings > Player' the [Internet Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzOkk.png) to Require. But there is still no sign of connection in the app. Does anyone know what the problem is? Thank in Advance!

```
public class CheckInternet : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool isInternet = false;
    public Text ConnectedText;
    public Text IntText;
    int i = 0;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        StartCoroutine (TestInternet());
        IntText.text = i++ + "";
        if (isInternet) {
            ConnectedText.text = "Connected";
        } else {
            ConnectedText.text = "Not Connected";
        }
    }

    IEnumerator TestInternet(){ 
        WWW internet = new WWW("www.google.com"); 
        yield return internet; 
        if(internet.error!=null) 
            isInternet=false; 
        else
            isInternet=true; 

    }
 }
```

[Source](https://github.com/KevinvdBurg/Check-Internet-Connection)

In the Play-Modes it had internet access: [image: PlayMode Internet Access]

And in the Android Build it has not Internet Access: [image: Android Build no Internet Acces]

Comment: If you're testing over 3g, then it might be a header issue. I believe 3g removes some headers from the packets it sends.

Comment: I tested it over Wifi and 4G LTE. Both resulted in "Not Connected"

Comment: Instead of putting "Not connected", try putting "internet.error" in your text field.  This should provide you with details as to why it failed, instead of just saying the connection failed.

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck at this for hours, but I came up with a solution. In case anyone's still stuck at this, here it is:

Unity on Android, or Android itself doesn't seem to like URL's without the protocol.

The fix is to add the protocol before the URL, for example your `www.google.com` would probably become `http://www.google.com` or `https://www.google.com`.

The error is explained perfectly in the `WWW.error` variable, that's what I didn't check.